# How to sum based on date condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table, and I need to create a query which will sum the value where all the `date` is no longer and equal to the `report_date`

```
group    report_date        date            value
a         2020-02-27          2020-02-18         3
a         2020-02-27          2020-02-19         3
a         2020-02-27          2020-02-20         4
a         2020-02-27          2020-02-21         3
a         2020-02-27          2020-02-22         2
a         2020-02-27          2020-02-23         1
a         2020-02-27          2020-02-24         2
a         2020-02-27          2020-02-25         3
a         2020-02-27          2020-02-26         5
a         2020-02-27          2020-02-27         2
a         2020-02-27          2020-02-28         2
```

In this example, I expect to get 28 from the query. How should I write my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select sum(value)
from tablename
where date<=report_date
```